# Word that means 'most common example'?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm having trouble thinking of a good example of this (I have a good example, but it doesn't make sense without context.)

Take this silly premise for the sake of explaining what I'm talking about: Imagine for a moment that whenever someone talks about a shape, the shape that ALWAYS springs to mind is square. Squares represent almost all shapes in people's minds, so when you talk about a shape, you might as well be talking about a square. In this situation, a square is the **_** example of a shape. Archetypal?

(I'd also be interested if anyone else has good examples -- that's better left for a comment)

Comment: Archetypal sounds good. Alternatives might be prototypical or canonical, maybe others.

Comment: Which word is the best ultimately depends on the context but chances are I'd go with "epitome."

Comment: Not exactly the meaning you're looking for, but I thought I'd mention *exemplar* as in "A square is a perfect exemplar of a generic shape."

Comment: I've now found an older question that has all the suggestions listed below, and more. Closing as duplicate, albeit I myself have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two words you might useful in this context:  archetype and quintessence.  Both words have significant overlap in meaning and usage; my comments below attempt to tease out their differences.

[Archetype](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/archetype), with the meaning "the original pattern or model from which all things of the same kind are copied or on which they are based; a model or first form; prototype", is appropriate if your intent is to present the subject in the abstract, as a model or some sort of universal template.  E.g. "The princess trapped in a tower is a literary archetype; Rapunzel is the archetypal example of this."

[Quintessence](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quintessence), with the meaning "the most perfect embodiment of something", is appropriate if you wish to focus attention on the subject.  E.g. "Disraeli was the quintessential statesman."

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are looking for the word *[canonical](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/canonical)*.

> Square is a canonical example of a shape.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite on the mark, but "[Quintessential](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=quintessential&button=Search)"

1. representing the perfect example of a class or quality;

Answer (score 1):

*Epitome*, as defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epitome):

> a perfect example : an example that represents or expresses something very well

[The Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/epitome?view=uk):

> A person or thing that is a perfect example of a particular quality or type

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epitome):

> 1. (of a class of items) The embodiment or encapsulation of.
> 2. (of a class of items) A representative example.

Note how that last one suggests another good option, *embodiment*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that "[Typical](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/typical)" has not been mentioned.

2 a.  combining or exhibiting the essential characteristics of a group